# Netbeans - New Entity Classes from Database wizard - slow scanning

Tags: java, oracle, netbeans

When using the New Entity Classes from Database wizard (NB7), it scans for all tables that my account has access. For a small database this pick list of available tables can be handy. However the account I'm using has access to thousands of tables causing the wizard to take hours to load!

Is there a way to specify the tables I want to use without loading the full pick list? Or a way of specifying tables using wild cards? I'd hate to have to hand craft the Entities or fall back to using JDeveloper!

I'm accessing an Oracle E Business Suite database using the Apps user id. I have no control over the database account to use or the accounts rights.

Comment: I do not think so... it sounds like this would be a good issue to file: http://netbeans.org/community/issues.html

Comment: It goes back to at least 2007. Bug 97739 - Improve speed for "Create Entity class from database" <http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97739>. Have the new Netbeans corporate overlords kept this deficiency in order to encourage use of JDeveloper when working with large COTS databases? :)

Comment: Fixed URL [link](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97739)

Comment: I don't think so...  but I work for those corporate overlords, so I may be biased. Last I checked, there were more fixes and enhancements than there are folks paid to work on them... so good stuff gets left on the to-do list because the current staff is really having a hard time keeping up with the 'must-do' list.